# Angular Accordion -Expand Collapsed Fails -No Event Fires

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to toggle my accordion list open and close from a button but it does not work.
Any ideas as to why the event is not firing?
This code --> is-open="$parent.opened" is suppose to toggle the is-open element true anf false thereby opening and closing accordion elements
Thanks

HERE IS MY CONTROLLER

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('programcontroller', ['$scope',function ($scope) {

        $scope.currentPage = 1;

        $scope.opened = true;

        }


    }]);
```

HERE IS MY WEB PAGE BODY

```
<body>
        <div ng-controller="programcontroller">  
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon-plus" ng-click="togglegroup()">Expand</button>
            <div data-ng-repeat="m in results">
                <div class="container panel-heading">
                    <accordion id="accordion_{{$index+((currentPage-1)*20)+1}}" close-others="false">
                        <accordion-group is-open="$parent.opened">
                            <accordion-heading>
                                {{m.ALabel}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': opened, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !opened}"></i>
                            </accordion-heading>
                            <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                            <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
                        </accordion-group>
                    </accordion>

                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tell me if that is what you want, on click on the button, bodies are hiding while heading are still visible

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="programcontroller">  
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon-plus"  ng-click="opened = !opened">Expand</button>
        <div data-ng-repeat="m in results">
            <div class="container panel-heading">
                <accordion id="accordion_{{$index+((currentPage-1)*20)+1}}" close-others="false">
                    <accordion-group is-open="$parent.opened">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            {{m.ALabel}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': opened, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !opened}"></i>
                        </accordion-heading>
                        <div  ng-show="opened">
                        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>

            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to collapse all of the accordion-group elements with a click of the button not collapse everything in the div. I want to still be able to show the heading titles <accordion-heading> for all of the accordion elements. Thanks

Comment: so, on the click on this button <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon-plus" ng-click="togglegroup()">Expand</button> you want that all body hide and heading still visible ?

Comment: It does not work. Clicking the button has no response. If I put an alert for opened scope value I can see the values change on click but the accordion body does not hide

Comment: try replace ng-show="opened" by ng-show="opened == true" ?

Comment: if it does not work, delete $scope.opened = true; and add ng-init="opened = true" after your controller and before your button (add a div)

Comment: Ok, it only works for one single panel. if I put the button inside the <accordion> tag. What I am trying to do is click a button outside of the accordion panel in order to close all of the panels at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using the angular UI bootstrap accordion. But their directive can be found here. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

Comment: try it but i'm not sure, put it in your directive and call the function in ng-click this.open = false;

this.toggleAll = function(open) {
 if(open == true) {
      angular.forEach(this.groups, function (group) {
          group.isOpen = false;
      });
   open == false;
   
 } else {
   open == true;
      angular.forEach(this.groups, function (group) {
          group.isOpen = true;
      });
 }
    
  };